# PHP "Go to Parent Page" Button on Directory Style URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, back

I was trying to find the solution throughout the web and I can't see any solution that applies to my problem.

I have a directory styled website: [link here](http://www.escolafengshui.com/)

And I also have a Back Button on every page. For now, the button sends the user back to the homepage, but what I want to do is to go back to the parent page.

For example, if the user is here "site.com/page/subpage", and they click on the back button, it should send them to "site.com/page".

I haven't found any solution to this. I'm willing to use jQuery or PHP.

I would really appreciate some help on this matter.

Thanks in advance,

Bruno

EDIT: My purpose is NOT to use the "history back", because if a user doesn't come from the parent page or if they come from any other site, it will send them back there. I don't want that, I want it to be a "go to parent page" button.

EDIT 2: **Theory**: My theory would be to get the whole url with:

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and trim it, removing the last part. For example, removing "/subpage" from "site.com/page/subpage"

Comment: The answer by @RasulIslam is the best one for this case, as it leverages built-in PHP functionality. Also, this kind of feature is called "bread crumbs". Searching for that phrase should lead to a lot more interesting results. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (javascript):

```
var url = window.location.href.split('/');
url.splice(url.length-1,1);
var pUrl = url.join('/');
window.location.href = pUrl;
```

Comment: Your solution works EXACTLY as I intended. It is highly unlikeable but what if the url ends with "/". I did a test and it went from "site.com/page/subpage/" to "site.com/page/subpage". Do you happen to know any way to fix it? It's not necessary but the solution would go from 99% perfect to 100%.

Comment: Ah i see. Maybe after split you can add an if check like if (url[url.length-1] == "") { url.splice(url.length-2,1); } else { url.splice(url.length-1,1); }. I have not tested this, maybe you can try it out and see.

Answer (score 2):

You can get parent directories path by using `dirname()` method of php.

```
$parentPath = dirname( $currentPath, 1)
```

Here 1 is the level you want to navigate. For example

```
$currentPath = "/page/subpage/anotherpage"
```

will return `/page/subpage`

Comment: This is the best answer, as it leverages the built-in functions that are made for just this task!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`history`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp) object :

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    history.back();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My purpose is NOT to use that, because, if a person comes from Google or any other website, it will redirect them back there.